# Lightbox2 - lb-number empty on start?

Tags: lightbox2

I'm using Lightbox2 for an upcoming project. There is a feature for lb-number where it will display a message saying 'Image 1 of 4' however this information isn't displayed until you click on a lightbox object.

I'd really like to use this information prior to clicking anything so the user knows how many images there are in the gallery.

Any help would be appreciated....

On page load...

```
<div class="lb-details">
    <span class="lb-caption"></span>
    <span class="lb-number"></span>
</div>
```

After image click...

```
<div class="lb-details">
    <span class="lb-caption" style="display: none;"></span>
    <span class="lb-number">Image 1 of 4</span>
</div>
```